# mysql throws error in console and stopping nodejs server

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, database

I am trying to handle the error of mysql query for deleting.

`

When the error is occurring, instead of executing the `response` function **MySQL** is throwing the error in the console and **stopping the server**.

`

This used to work before, but now it is not working now.

***Is this because of any version of MySQL and nodejs??***

.

I am using node js version: `v10.6.0`.

MySQL connector version: `^2.16.0`.

.

*I have created a relationship between two tables with restricting delete.*

.

**This is my code to delete an item from the table.**

```
this.deletePurchaseBill = function (id) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var delete_purchase_bill_sql = `DELETE FROM purchase_entry_header WHERE id = '${id}'`;
        conn.query(delete_purchase_bill_sql, function (err, result) {
            console.log('error:' + err);
            if (err) {
                if (err.errno == 1451) {
                    resolve({
                        status: "error",
                        message: "This purchase can not be deleted",
                        debug: err,
                    });
                } else {
                    resolve({
                        status: "error",
                        message: "Unexpected error occurred",
                        debug: err
                    });
                }
            } else {
                resolve({
                    status: "success",
                    message: "Successfully Deleted"
                });
            }
        });
    });
};
```

.

*Any help would be appriceated*

Comment: Why haven't you rejected in case of the error?

Comment: @SirajAlam  didn't do that because I need to show the error to the end-user. Is that why the server is crashing?

Comment: @HelloWorld as far as I know even though mySql will throw an error because of node js non-blocking method, the server wont stop. it will only not return the error to the end-user

Comment: @Ji-Yong this used to work before without any problem, but from few days I have been getting this issue.